# Triggering Java & Selenium automation in Attlasian (TEST AIO)

Tags: java, selenium, jira, python-jira

I am searching and i don't know how could i execute a JAVA automation using the Attlasian tool called AIO TEST:

[image]

I have a program .java and it runs just fine but i would like to trigger this java program by calling it directly from AIO TEST.

Is there any way to achieve that? Have you ever done something like that?

Comment: From what i see in their documentation most of the operations are done via their api.  They have plugins for Jenkins/BitBucket CI servers. The AIO Tests plugin in Jira mostly used for visualizing and mapping of the results of your automation. https://aioreports.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ATDoc/pages/803373071/Jenkins+-+Continuous+Integration

Comment: The triggering should happen in the CI server (time schedule or code change) rather than from Jira.

Comment: Hey @AlexKaramfilov thanks for commenting :). Yeah, i found something similar but i am having trouble trying to set everything. I do have my java application and now, what? WHat should i do first based on the documentation?. I'm kinda lost :/

Comment: In order for this to work your next step is to configure Jenkins/BitBucket CI pipeline/job where you should execute your tests. Depending on your CI server option you will need to use different plugins/configurations. It will require some time unfortunately. Its not just a simple command.

Comment: @AlexKaramfilov Alex, suppose i managed to configure Jenkins/BitBucket CI pipeline/job, i am not understanding how that may "connect" to JIRA - AIO TEST. I was trying to have something like this: "run a script from AIO TEST called test1 and somehow obtain the output from that and paste in the comments". Something like "TEST 1: 0 FAILURES" or "TEST 1: 1 FAILURES"

Answer (score 1):

AIO Tests does not support triggering tests from within the application.  The process to achieve reporting results to AIO Tests would be as follows:

1. Generate an AIO Tests API Key [[Ref]](https://aioreports.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ATDoc/pages/484048912/Access+Token).  This would authenticate you to AIO Tests in Jira.
2. You can trigger your automation runs from any CI/CD server.  If you are using Jenkins and using any of the testing frameworks from (TestNG/JUnit/NUnit/Postman/Cucumber) or are able to generate the JUnit report or Cucumber report, you can use the [AIO Tests Jenkins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/aio-tests/) plugin as a post build step to report results.
3. If you are not using the plugin, then use the API Key to report results to your cases in AIO Tests.  The APIs available for reporting are available @ [AIO Tests Swagger documentation.](https://tcms.aiojiraapps.com/aio-tcms/aiotcms-static/api-docs/#/)